# $S$ is closed under finite intersections given $S_1 \cap S_2 \in S$ for all $S_1, S_2 \in S$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Say $S$ is a set of subsets of $A$. Suppose we know $S_1 \cap S_2 \in S$ for all $S_1, S_2 \in S$.

I'm trying to figure out *if $S$ is closed under finite intersections.*

I've heard that "closed under finite intersections" means that if $S_1,S_2,…,S_k$ are each in the set, then their mutual intersection $S_1\cap S_2\cap⋯\cap S_k$ is in the set. This only works for a finite collection of elements $k < \infty$.

We are told to suppose that for all $S_i \in S$, the intersection of two $S_i$ is also in $S$. Hence we know that for a finite number of subsets $S_i$ of $A$, all unions will also be in $S$. This seems to be exactly the definition of "closed under finite intersection". At least, I think this is the case.

Does anyone have a more thorough proof for this concept or thoughts on how to express it? Am I just missing some common definition?

EDIT: Basically, I'm looking to make sure that the given information leads to the definition of "closed under finite intersections" and it seems like a one-step process.

Comment: Isn't the very definition of that property of S the same as "closed under finite intersections"? Perhaps a little induction to make things slightly more formal, but that's all...is this what you're asking ?

Comment: I had a professor write down the first two sentences and then say "you should be able to see very easily that this S is closed under finite intersection". I think it's pretty straightforward, but want to make sure I'm not missing any steps. Are you thinking of something specific when you mention induction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As DonAntonio alludes to, closure under finite intersections follows by induction: The case $n=1$ is trivial. Suppose that $\bigcap_{k=1}^n S_k\in S$ for all $S_1,...,S_n\in S$. Let $S_1,...,S_n,S_{n+1}\in S$. Then $$\bigcap_{k=1}^{n+1}S_k=\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^n S_k\right)\bigcap S_{n+1}\in S,$$ and we are done.

Comment: It was as simple as it seemed. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @BobMcdonald Generally speaking, if something works for combining a pair of sets together via unions, intersections, Cartesian products etc., and you want it to work for any $n$, induction will be an invaluable technique

Comment: @BobMcdonald If my answer has adequately resolved your question, please consider accepting :)